# Bootstrap 3.x like Grid Column Ordering in Bootstrap 2.3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Now I know Bootstrap 3.x is out and I should be moving to 3.x. But, this is a change request that has come up in an existing site that uses Bootstrap 2.3.1.

Here's the thing, that I want to achieve:

I am using a 3 column layout in the 12-column bootstrap grid as:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='span3'></div>
  <div class='span6'></div>
  <div class='span3'></div>
</div>
```

The desired responsive behavior is:

**Large screens:**

```
[ X ][ Y Y ][ Z ]
```

**Tablet portrait:**

```
[ Y    Y ]
[ X ][ Z ]
```

**Smaller screens:**

```
[YY]
[X]
[Z]
```

Now, I know this can be achieved using [grid column ordering of Bootstrap 3.x](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering). But, I need to achieve this using Bootstrap 2.3.

[*Fiddle for those willing to give this a try!*](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/3f969/)

Comment: as of I know, it is not possible to achieve this through bs 2.x.x. You have to migrate to bs 3.x.x

Comment: @Ravimallya Please read the question again. Migrating an entire site to Bootstrap 3.x for this layout change at one place is not an option. Also, I realize that there no straight forward solution to this problem. But, its not that this can't be achieved. My last resort is to go with a script based solution that reorders DOM elements for me to achieve desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 2.x.x, the row has minus left margin and span-x have left margin to get gutter. If the second span stacked into next row, it will have left margin for sure.

My suggestion is download grid only from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and append to existing bootstrap css or in a custom css. use the new grid system to get what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

one way to achieve this without altering bootstrap 2.3 css is

```
<div class='row'> 
    <div class='span6 hidden-desktop visible-tablet visible-phone'>YY</div>
    <div class='span3'>X</div>
    <div class='span6 visible-desktop hidden-tablet hidden-phone'>YY</div>
    <div class='span3'>Z</div>
</div>
```

please see http://jsfiddle.net/houssamk/3f969/2/

Comment: This comes pretty close to what I ended up doing. Although your fiddle does not show the intermediate, tablet layout where [X] and [Z] are to be shown alongside, it's a good starting point. The only disadvantage though was the rendering overhead of loading the [YY] twice and managing conflicts that might arise due to duplication of ids of elements contained within the [YY] screen.